# Proving that the series 1 + ... + $1 / \sqrt{x}$ < $2 \sqrt{x}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, proof-writing, induction

Proving that the series 1 + ... + $1 / \sqrt{x}$ < $2 \sqrt{x}$

I am doing it by simple induction adding
$1/\sqrt{x+1}$ to both sides, but I can't find a way to manipulate this expression and find that the new series is $< 2 \sqrt{x+1}$.

Can someone show me the correct process?

I failed many times and the furthest I've gotten has been to prove that it's $< 2 \sqrt{x+1} + 1$ which is close, but not enough.

Comment: can you elaborate what the series $1 + ... + 1/\sqrt{x} < 2\sqrt{x}$ is? (I mean the intermediate terms)

Comment: Is $x$ an integer?

Comment: What is your summand? It's not quite clear from just the first and last cases. Are you computing $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ for some integer $x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the induction step, you need to show that
$$2\sqrt{x}+\frac1{\sqrt{x+1}}< 2\sqrt{x+1}$$
$$\frac1{\sqrt{x+1}}< 2(\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt x)$$
Multiplying both sides by $\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}$, we have:
$$\iff \frac{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+1}}< 2 $$
$$\iff \frac{\sqrt x}{\sqrt{x+1}}< 1$$
which is now obvious.

Comment: How do you assume 2 will be greater than everything on the left after multiplying both sides by $\sqrt{x+1} - \sqrt{x}$

Comment: @DanielOrtizCosta oh sorry, missed a typo. Check again.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand how to get the proof going backwards. But  assuming I start from $1 > \sqrt{n} / \sqrt{n+1}$ and build it onwards, how do I go from the last step, to the step - 1, in other words, how do I know that will be less than 2 after adding the $\sqrt{x+1}$ to the numerator.

Comment: You don't work backwards. For induction, you assume it works for $x$ and show that implies it works for $x+1$. Then if you have a base case done, it will hold true for all greater integers.

Comment: What I mean is that I will start by showing that $1 > \sqrt{x} / \sqrt{x+1}$, then build it step by step until I get $2\sqrt{x+1} > (2\sqrt{x}) + (1/\sqrt{x+1})$.

Comment: Because it would be interesting to see how would the steps be proved if done in reverse, but it is not needed. Anyway, what I am also wondering, can the first line of your proof be done with $\leq$ and not necessarily <? From the beginning we don't really know if it is going to be <.

Comment: I think I get what you're trying now. Will rewrite later in detail.

Comment: I found how to justify it, it was simple by just transforming it into a different form. Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose $x$ is an integer and you series is 
$$1+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+\dots+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$
For $n=1,$ our inequity is obviously true.
Suppose it is true for $n=k.$ Then 
$$1+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+\dots+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k}}<2\sqrt{k}$$ 
$$1+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+\dots+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}<2\sqrt{k}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$$  Note that 
$$\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}>\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{k+1}}.$$ Hence $$\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{k+1}}+\sqrt{k}<\sqrt{k+1}$$ and therefore 
$$1+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+\dots+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}<2\sqrt{k+1}$$ Therefore by MI, our result is true for all $n\in\mathbb{N}.$

Answer (score 2):

We can notice that:
$$ \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}}\in\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n+1}},\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\right), $$
hence:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}< 2\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1}\right) = 2\sqrt{N}$$
as wanted. On the other hand, we also have:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}> 2\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\right) = 2\sqrt{N+1}-2.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum^n_{k=1}k^{-\frac 1 2}<\int_0^nx^{-\frac 1 2}\ \text{d}x=2n^{\frac 1 2}$$

Since the first value is a lower Riemann sum for the integral in the middle.